# Add border and preserve radius already there

Tags: css

I have a box which has a radius - I want to apply a border to that but when I do the 'inner' box is back to being square edged, is this possible?

CSS

```
.box {
width:100px;
height:50px;
background:red;
border-radius:6px;
margin:20px;
}

.box2 {
width:100px;
height:50px;
background:red;
border-radius:6px;
margin:20px;
border:5px solid #ccc;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

As you can see the second box has the border but I want to preserve the inner radius too.

Fiddle here: [CSS border Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/5Qvgq/)

Comment: Double it up, changing the border-radius to 12px fixes it: http://jsfiddle.net/5Qvgq/1/

Comment: @Andy: Hmmm, I'm not sure if doubling the radius or doubling the border width will produce a closer result to what's intended, since the radius and width are almost the same. I'm not even sure I can produce exactly equally-rounded corners. Let me experiment...

Comment: @Andy: Found it, edited and undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The border is too thick for its inner radius to be visibly rounded. You will have to increase the second box's `border-radius` if you want to see the inner corners rounded.

You can get your second box to have identical rounded corners to your first box by taking the first box's `border-radius` and adding the second box's `border-width` to it. So for an inner radius of `6px` (from your first box) with `border-width: 5px`, you have `border-radius: 11px` on the second box.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/5Qvgq/3)

Answer (score 0):

You could use box-shadow to get the desired effect:

```
box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #ccc;
```

See in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTgYx/)

Comment: That's not the same as a border - it may affect the layout in unexpected ways if it depends on the border for calculating dimensions.

Comment: You are right, using a bigger border-radius will prevent that problem. This solution works best if you don't want to change the border radius of the elements that do have a border.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this to have the effect of a completely rounded border:

CSS:

```
.box {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    border-radius:6px;
    margin:20px;
}

.box2 {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:#ccc;
    border-radius:6px;
    margin:20px;
    border:5px solid #ccc;
}

.boxinbox {
    background:red;
    border-radius:6px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="boxinbox"></div>
  </div>
```